# Filter rows after last row with data, keep gaps in place

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

Google App Script: 
I've used `sslink.getRange("C2:C").getValues().filter(String);` but it removes gaps(rows without data).

Is there a way to keep in between rows without data, but remove all rows after the last row?

For example, I have data

`a = [a,b,,c,d,,e,,,,,]`

I'd like to find index of `e`(a non empty array, the last could be f, g, h, etc.) so I can remove the rest of the data simply by doing:

`a.length = 7`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the values in your array are strings then something like this might work for you:

```js
var a = ['a', 'b', '', 'c', 'd', '', 'e', '', '', '', '', ''];

function removeTrailingSpaces(array) {
  while (array[array.length - 1].length === 0) {
    array.pop();
  }
}

removeTrailingSpaces(a);
console.log(a);
console.log(a.length);
```

Comment: Very elegant solution! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function getData(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++){
    vA[i]=vA[i].slice(2,3);
  }
  while(!vA[vA.length-1][0]){
    vA.splice(vA.length-1,1);
  }
  return vA
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`C2:C` is a 2D array and doesn't look like `a`.  Use a reverse loop to determine the last element index.

#### Snippet:

```
var a=[["a"],["b"],[""],["c"],["d"],[""],["e"],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""]];
var i= a.length;
while(i--){
 if(a[i][0] !== ""){break;}
}
a.length=++i;
```